# AlarmManager only one alarm works

Tags: android, time, notifications, alarmmanager

I've read tons of questions here and they all have the same answer, use a unique ID for the pending intent, but I am doing this already and it still doesn't work. I can add one alarm but if I add more not only do they not work but they make the original alarm not work as well. Modifying an alarm breaks it too.

```
    pIntent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, row, notificationBroadcast, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pIntent);
```

I've used set() as well and I have the same problem, so it's not caused by setRepeating.

Comment: @ChrisKnight row is the row id from my database. Hypothetically each row should have a different alarm.

Comment: Have you tried replacing ``PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`` with 0?

Comment: @ChrisKnight yes, that did not work.

Comment: Could you post your whole code

Comment: @LotusUNSW I'm afraid I cannot post my whole code. Do you have no idea why it is behaving so strangely?

Comment: It has to do with the ID you pass to the pending intent, therefore try to log the values you have for the alarm ID when they are being set to ensure each time you set the alarm a different ID is indeed used, then report.

Comment: @kabuto178 I have done that, it's a different one every time.

Comment: You sure the alarmTime is ok as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think problem solving is:

```
<receiver android:name="com.myapp.alarmmanagerexample.AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

In manifest